# What a periodic function needs to satisfy so its integral will be a periodic function?

Tags: integration, periodic-functions

I have a periodic function $g(x)$. I want to know what else $g(x)$ has to satisfy so its undefined integral will be a periodic function.

Thanks!

PS: I noticed that if $g(x)=f(x)+a$ where $a$ is a constant the integral will not be periodic.

Comment: What kind of integral are you considering? Defined integral, undefined integral, … ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oh, thank you, I haven't found this question while searching. It is quite similar but I would like a more detailed answer if possible.

Comment: @JJacquelin Undefined, I'll add this detail, thanks!

Comment: If $g$ is periodic and integrable, let $G$ denote its indefinite integral. The _definite_ integral of $g$ over one period exists; call it $\Delta$. If $\Delta\ne 0$, then $G(x)=G(x+p)-\Delta=G(x+2p)-2\Delta=G(x+3p)-3\Delta=\dots$ (where $p$ is the period of $g$), and this infinite sequence of values shows that $G$ cannot be periodic in that case. On the other hand, if $\Delta=0$, it is straightforward to see that $G(x)=G(x+p)$ for all $x$, so in that case $G$ is periodic with the same period as $g$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen oh, ok! Thank you very much!